# Paste 2 data frames side by side without any key

Tags: r, merge, dplyr, reshape2, melt

I have two data frames

```
A   B    E   H  
x1  x2  x3  x6  
x1  x2  x4  x7  
x1  x2  x5  x8
```

and

```
A   B     
y1  y2    
y1  y2
```

and this is what i would like to achieve with dplyr or reshape2

```
A   B    E   H  A   B   
x1  x2  x3  x6  y1  y2  
x1  x2  x4  x7  y1  y2   
x1  x2  x5  x8
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the number of rows are same use

```
cbind(df1, df2)
#   A  B  E  H  A  B
#1 x1 x2 x3 x6 y1 y2
#2 x1 x2 x4 x7 y1 y2
#3 x1 x2 x5 x8 y1 y2
```

---

Or in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df2 %>% 
       rename_all(~ str_c(., ".1")) %>%
       bind_cols(df1, .)
```

In some versions of `dplyr` (`0.8.5`), it would rename correctly when there are duplicate column names

```
bind_cols(df1, df2)
```

NOTE: It is not recommended to have same column names in `data.frame` so we could change the column names with `make.unique`

---

If we have two datasets with unequal number of rows

```
library(rowr)
cbind.fill(df1, df2new, fill = NA)
#   A  B  E  H    A    B
#1 x1 x2 x3 x6   y1   y2
#2 x1 x2 x4 x7   y1   y2
#3 x1 x2 x5 x8 <NA> <NA>
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
mxn <- max(nrow(df1), nrow(df2new))
df2new[(nrow(df2new)+1):mxn,] <- NA
cbind(df1, df2new)
#   A  B  E  H    A    B
#1 x1 x2 x3 x6   y1   y2
#2 x1 x2 x4 x7   y1   y2
#3 x1 x2 x5 x8 <NA> <NA>
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c("x1", "x1", "x1"), B = c("x2", "x2", "x2"
), E = c("x3", "x4", "x5"), H = c("x6", "x7", "x8")),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df2 <- structure(list(A = c("y1", "y1", "y1"), B = c("y2", "y2", "y2"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2new <- structure(list(A = c("y1", "y1"), B = c("y2", "y2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: At least the `dplyr::bind_cols(df1, df2)` even if you take no action automatically renames the second column `A` to `A1`

Comment: @ChuckP In my version, it is doing `A...1 B...2  E  H A...5 B...6`.   I am using the devel version of dplyr and that could be the difference

Comment: I'm running 0.8.5 but regardless it's  better than having a new_df with overlapping column names which is what `cbind` will do.

Comment: @ChuckP you are right.  thank you for showing the version

Comment: Actually keeping overlapping names is cbind "feature" comparing to a data.frame() function, which would do the same but make names unique. Just stacking data.frames is not a stacking+renaming. Both functions have own use cases.

Comment: What if the two data frame are of different length?

Comment: thanks @akrun. The issue is that apparently the package rowr has been remove from cran is there any other package available to do this command?